# Is there a term for a class of conjugacy by elements of a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

The conjugacy class of an element $a$ of a group $G$ is defined to be the set of elements $gag^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$. I have an application where I only want to consider conjugation by elements of a subgroup $S \leq G$, i.e. the set of elements $sas^{-1}$ for all $s \in S$. (However, $a$ is not necessarily in $S$, so I can't just restrict my "universe of consideration" to $S$.)

Is there a standard term for such an equivalent class? Something shorter than "the conjugacy class of $a$ with respect to conjugation by elements of $S$"?

Comment: How about the conjugacy orbit with respect to $S$? I don't think there is a much more concise way

Comment: How about $a^S$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Is that a standard use of the superscript notation? I've never seen that.

Comment: @tparker It’s standard notation any time a group action is involved, yes. If a group element $g$ acts on a set element $x$, it’s common to write $x^g$. You can find this notation in e.g. *Permutation Groups* by Dixon and Mortimer or *Algebraic Graph Theory* by Godsil and Royle.

Comment: Since $S$ is a subgroup, this does not affect my comment above, but I strongly dislike the notation $x^g$ for $gxg^{-1}$, because it mixes right and left actions, which can lead to confusion and mistakes. It is better to use ${}^gx$ for $gxg^{-1}$ and have $x^g = g^{-1}xg$.